# Remove first two chars from string in makefile?

Tags: makefile

How do I remove the first two characters from a string in a makefile?

On windows, suppose I have:

```
ROOT_DIR := $(dir $(realpath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
```

Then later, I have:

```
WINTOOLS := $(ROOT_DIR)/../../wintools
GOWTOOLS := $(WINTOOLS))/Gow/bin
```

My GOWTOOLS variable has, for example: "L:/path/to/project/../../wintools/Gow/bin".  Now, If I try to run a command from there, say:

```
$(GOWTOOLS)/sed -e xxxxx
```

I get the error message "**'L:' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**"

If I manually enter the path minus the L:., it works fine.  If I flip the slashes, it works fine.

How can I, in Makefile-ese, drop the drive specifier from the tools dir string?

Comment: I'll just leave you a link to the [GNU make Standard Library](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/), which has a `substr` function. If you look at the implementation of it, you'll abandon all ambitions to implement it yourself, though. If not that, then perhaps `$(shell)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of a good way to drop two characters offhand but you can use the fact that `:` isn't legal in a Windows file path/name and do something like:

```
GOWTOOLS := $(subst :, ,$(WINTOOLS))/Gow/bin)
GOWTOOLS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(GOWTOOLS),$(GOWTOOLS))
```

But if `If I flip the slashes, it works fine` is true then it might be simpler/safer to use (since neither `/` nor `\` are legal in path names either):

```
GOWTOOLS := $(subst /,\,$(WINTOOLS))/Gow/bin)
```